# Marker Augmented Reality for android with framework Pro Android Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, marker

I Create AR Apps with framework Pro Android Augmented Reality Chapter 8
This Link https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality

I want to create a Marker that is not black and white. 
How to Create Marker that is not Black and White ? or Sample Code ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

(I'm the author of the book in question, and a developer of the framework it uses)

AndAR supports colored markers out of the box, and you don't need to do anything special to use them. Just plug them in like the black and white ones.

You can generate your own markers from [here](http://flash.tarotaro.org/ar/MarkerGeneratorOnline.swf), using the online flash tool and a webcam.

Keep in mind that your colors should be high contrast, so that detection is of good accuracy. Using similar colors is going to reduce the detection accuracy.

Comment: I'm creating a project., By marker that I use it as a marker to the general picture. Was not a black marker. General squares.

Recommend me please.

Comment: @PetchchJonh I'm not sure I understand the comment. By general picture and squares if you mean something like a colored chessboard, you should be fine. If you mean something like a family photo with lots of different things in it, you're going to have an accuracy problem.

Comment: Yes,I mean family photo
Your Framework chapter 8 Support ?
If support , How do I do ?

Comment: @PetchchJonh Those won't work, unless you have a really good camera, in a really good lighting situation, and near perfect angle alignment to the angle you were holding it when making the marker file.

Comment: [Good color marker](http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2012/203/a/d/red_green_blue_white_squares_by_10binary-d589c0e.png) - [Bad Color Marker](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Mona_Lisa.jpg)

Comment: I studied framework of metaio.
This framework can be used as a marker image. I'm not sure if you do or do not framwork.

Thanks

Comment: @PetchchJonh From what I've seen in their promotional videos, their markers are pretty high contrast, with clear edges and lines in them. A family photo is likely to have variable lighting, and lots of soft edges, which will reduce accuracy.

Comment: If I want a marker of framework metaio., It can be done or not.

Comment: @PetchchJonh Once again, I'm not sure what you're saying in the comment. Perhaps you could email the metaio support an image of your proposed marker and ask them if it will work?